# Looking for a solution to replace tags in a loop where template also contains tables

Tags: loops, tags, docx

I have the following docx file:

%LOOP=PolicyRelationship,NAME=Life,KEY=(PolicyNo=Policy.PolicyNo,Relation='INSR')%
%Life.EntityNo% - %Life.Name1% %Life.Name2%

%ENDLOOP%

*The following is a table with a header row*

Cover Type  Sum Insured Modal Premium
BenefitVal  SumValue    ModalValue

This is the last line of the document.

I am looping through LOOP blocks iteratively - replacing each variable with data
All remaining text is being cut from wordDoc and pasted to remainingParagraphs then re-pasted at the end after the loop values have been pasted back in

Not all paragraphs are being processed this way due to the condition

if (wordDoc.Paragraphs[i].ParentContainer == Container.Body)

condition. Without this condition all paragraphs are processed in the right order but the XML is corrupt. With this condition the table values are not transferred and thus appear incorrectly BEFORE the loop values.

If there is a simpler approach without all the cutting and pastings that would be ideal

This is my current code snippet:

```
   private void ProcessRepeatingText(DocX wordDoc, Dictionary<string, DocumentView> views)
    {
        var textDoc = wordDoc.Text;

        var opn = 0;
        while (opn != -1)
        {
            int cls, cma;
            string tag, dto, rsn, key, where;
            object repo;

            //
            // Get each loop DataView that has been defined, select a collection of data and store it in "views"
            //
            opn = textDoc.IndexOf("%LOOP=", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (opn == -1) break;
            cls = textDoc.IndexOf("%", opn + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            tag = textDoc.Substring(opn, cls - opn + 1);
            cma = tag.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            dto = tag.Substring(6, cma - 6);
            opn = tag.IndexOf("NAME=", cma, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            cls = tag.IndexOf(",", opn + 5, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            rsn = tag.Substring(opn + 5, cls - opn - 5);
            cma = tag.IndexOf(",", cls, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            opn = tag.IndexOf("KEY=(", cma, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            cls = tag.IndexOf(")", opn + 4, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            key = tag.Substring(opn + 5, cls - opn - 5);
            where = BuildWhereClause(dto, key, views);
            repo = _baseRepository.CreateInstance(dto + "Repository");
            var sec = repo.GetType().GetMethod("GetWhere").Invoke(repo, new object[] { where });
            views.Add(rsn, new DocumentView { Rsn = rsn, Dto = dto, Data = sec, Pointer = 0 });
            var loopTag = tag;

            var i = -1;
            var startAt = 0;
            var tagBlocks = new List<TagBlock>();
            opn = textDoc.IndexOf(loopTag, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            while (opn != -1)
            {
                if (textDoc.Substring(opn, 6) == "%LOOP=")
                {
                    i++;
                    cls = textDoc.IndexOf("%", opn + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    tagBlocks.Add(new TagBlock { From = opn, Upto = -1, FromIndex = -1, UptoIndex = -1 });
                    tagBlocks[i].FromIndex = IndexOfParagraph(wordDoc, textDoc.Substring(opn, cls - opn + 1), ref startAt);
                    opn = opn + 6;
                }
                if (textDoc.Substring(opn, 8) == "%ENDLOOP")
                {
                    tagBlocks[i].Upto = opn;
                    if (tagBlocks[i].FromIndex != -1)
                    {
                        tagBlocks[i].UptoIndex = IndexOfParagraph(wordDoc, textDoc.Substring(opn, 9), ref startAt);
                    }
                    i--;
                    opn = opn + 8;
                }
                if (i == -1) break;
                opn++;
            }

            var remainingParagraphs = new List<Novacode.Paragraph>();
            for (i = tagBlocks[0].UptoIndex + 1; i < wordDoc.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
            //    if (wordDoc.Paragraphs[i].ParentContainer == ContainerType.Body)
            //    {
                    remainingParagraphs.Add(wordDoc.Paragraphs[i]);
                    wordDoc.RemoveParagraphAt(i);
                    i--;
            //    }
            }

            var loopDoc = DocX.Create(new MemoryStream());
            if (tagBlocks[0].FromIndex != -1)
            {
                if (tagBlocks[0].UptoIndex != -1)
                {
                    for (i = tagBlocks[0].FromIndex + 1; i < tagBlocks[0].UptoIndex; i++)
                    {
                        loopDoc.InsertParagraph(wordDoc.Paragraphs[i]);
                    }
                    for (i = tagBlocks[0].UptoIndex; i > tagBlocks[0].FromIndex; i--)
                    {
                        wordDoc.RemoveParagraphAt(i);
                    }
                }
                wordDoc.RemoveParagraphAt(tagBlocks[0].FromIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                opn = tagBlocks[0].From;
                cls = textDoc.IndexOf("%", opn + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                tag = textDoc.Substring(opn, cls - opn + 1);
                var paragraph = wordDoc.Paragraphs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Contains(tag));
                if (paragraph != null)
                {
                    paragraph.ReplaceText(tag, "");
                    paragraph.ReplaceText("%ENDLOOP%", "");
                }
            }
            var loopTxt = loopDoc.Text;

            //
            // Now get the secondary DataView data from "views"
            //
            DocumentView view;
            if (views.TryGetValue(rsn, out view) != true)
            {
                return;
            }

            view.Pointer = 0;
            var list = (IList)view.Data;

            for (view.Pointer = 0; view.Pointer < list.Count; view.Pointer++)
            {
                var item = list[view.Pointer];

                //
                // Process conditional text, with a dependency on this secondary RSN, within this loop
                //
                loopTxt = ProcessConditionalText(loopDoc, view.Rsn, views, loopTxt);

                //
                // Process repeating text (LOOP..ENDLOOP) with a dependency on this secondary RSN
                //
                ProcessRepeatingText(loopDoc, views);

                //
                // Perform the data tag replacements, for this RSN, within this loop
                //
                ReplaceParameters(loopDoc, item, view.Rsn);


                foreach (var p in loopDoc.Paragraphs)
                {
                    wordDoc.InsertParagraph(p);
                }

            }

            foreach (var p in remainingParagraphs)
            {
                wordDoc.InsertParagraph(p);
            }

            wordDoc.Paragraphs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Text == loopTag)?.Remove(false);
            wordDoc.ReplaceText(loopTag, "");
            textDoc = wordDoc.Text;
            views.Remove(rsn);

            opn = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I cut and paste sections of a Docx to another and keep the parent/child relationship in tact ?